# Make pagination stay on the center of the page

Tags: html, css, pagination

Currently my pagination changes its alignment slightly if you are on the first page or on the last page. When you go to the rest pages, the pagination stays in the center between the buttons "Next" and "Back" which appears only in this case. If you are on the first page, there is only "Next" button; when you're on the last page, there is only "Back" button. In both cases my pagination kind of sticks to these buttons leaving the center position.

Here is my HTML:

```
<template>
 <nav v-if="pagination.total_pages > 1" class="text-center g-mt-5">
  <ul class="list-inline">
   <li v-if="!pagination.first_page" class="list-inline-item float-sm-left">
    <router-link class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-16"
                 :to="getLinkToPreviousPage()">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left g-mr-5"></i>
      Back
    </router-link>
  </li>

  <li class="list-inline-item g-hidden-sm-down"
      v-if="pagination.current_page > (2)">
    <router-link class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-14"
                 :to="getLinkToPage(1)">1</router-link>
  </li>

  <li class="list-inline-item g-hidden-sm-down"
      v-if="pagination.total_pages > 3 && pagination.current_page > 3">
    <span class="g-pa-7-14">...</span>
  </li>

  <li class="list-inline-item g-hidden-sm-down"
      v-if="!!pagination.prev_page">
    <router-link class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-14"
                 :to="getLinkToPage(pagination.prev_page)">
      {{ pagination.prev_page }}
    </router-link>
  </li>

  <li class="list-inline-item g-hidden-sm-down">
    <a class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 u-pagination-v1-4--active g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-14"
       href="javascript: void(0);">
      {{ pagination.current_page }}
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="list-inline-item g-hidden-sm-down"
      v-if="!!pagination.next_page">
    <router-link class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-14"
                 :to="getLinkToPage(pagination.next_page)">
      {{ pagination.next_page }}
    </router-link>
  </li>

  <li class="list-inline-item g-hidden-sm-down"
      v-if="pagination.current_page < (pagination.total_pages - 2)">
    <span class="g-pa-7-14">...</span>
  </li>

  <li class="list-inline-item g-hidden-sm-down"
      v-if="pagination.current_page < (pagination.total_pages - 1)">
    <router-link class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-14"
                 :to="getLinkToPage(pagination.total_pages)">
      {{ pagination.total_pages  }}
    </router-link>
  </li>

  <li v-if="!pagination.last_page"
      class="list-inline-item float-sm-right">
    <router-link class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-16"
                 :to="getLinkToNextPage()">
      Next
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right g-ml-5"></i>
    </router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</template>
```

Here is CSS:

```
/*------------------------------------
Paginations
------------------------------------*/
/* Pagination v1 */
.u-pagination-v1__item {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border: solid 1px transparent;
transition: all .3s ease;
}

.u-pagination-v1__item--active, .u-pagination-v1__item:hover, .u-pagination-v1__item:focus {
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.u-pagination-v1__item-info {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
}

.u-pagination-v1__item--disabled {
opacity: .5;
pointer-events: none;
}

/* Pagination Style v1 */
.u-pagination-v1-1 {
color: #999;
border-color: #999;
}

.u-pagination-v1-1--active, .u-pagination-v1-1:hover, .u-pagination-v1-1:focus {
background-color: #0cbb67;
color: #fff;
border-color: #0cbb67;
}

/* Pagination Style v2 */
.u-pagination-v1-2 {
color: #555;
border-color: #555;
}

.u-pagination-v1-2:hover, .u-pagination-v1-2:focus {
color: #0cbb67;
border-color: #0cbb67;
}

.u-pagination-v1-2--active, .u-pagination-v1-2--nav {
background-color: #0cbb67;
color: #fff;
border-color: #0cbb67;
}

.u-pagination-v1-2--active:hover, .u-pagination-v1-2--active:focus, .u-pagination-v1-2--nav:hover, .u-pagination-v1-2--nav:focus {
color: #fff;
}

.u-pagination-v1-2--nav:hover {
background-color: rgba(114, 192, 44, 0.8);
}

/* Pagination Style v3 */
.u-pagination-v1-3 {
color: #333;
border-color: #333;
}

.u-pagination-v1-3--active, .u-pagination-v1-3:hover, .u-pagination-v1-3:focus {
background-color: #333;
color: #fff;
border-color: #333;
}

/* Pagination Style v4 */
.u-pagination-v1-4 {
color: #333;
border-color: transparent;
}

.u-pagination-v1-4:hover, .u-pagination-v1-4:focus {
color: #0cbb67;
border-color: #0cbb67;
}

.u-pagination-v1-4--active {
color: #fff;
background-color: #0cbb67;
border-color: #0cbb67;
}

.u-pagination-v1-4--active:hover, .u-pagination-v1-4--active:focus {
color: #fff;
}

/* Pagination Style v5 */
.u-pagination-v1-5 {
color: #999;
border-color: #ccc;
}

.u-pagination-v1-5--active, .u-pagination-v1-5:hover, .u-pagination-v1-5:focus {
background-color: #0cbb67;
color: #fff;
border-color: #0cbb67;
}
```

Is there any CSS trick to make my pagination stay on the center independently from the navigating buttons?

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe it's good to shouw us the final HTML and also your CSS

Comment: The problem is that I did not write CSS, it was the designer's responsibility. I added more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;}
body, html { margin:0; padding:0;}
.boxmain { width:100%; padding:0 20px; overflow:hidden;}
.box { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; width:31.1%; margin:0 1%; height:100px; background:#f1f1f1;}

.pagination { overflow:hidden; text-align:center; padding:0; position:relative; margin:20px 40px;}
.pagination .navlink  { position:absolute; top:0;}
.pagination .nextlink { right:0;}
.pagination .prevlink { left:0;}
.midbox { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
.midbox a { display:block; width:30px; height:30px; color:#000; text-align:center; border-radius:100%; float:left; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<div class="boxmain">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    <div class="navlink prevlink">Prev</div>
    <div class="midbox">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navlink nextlink">Next</div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    <div class="navlink prevlink" style="display:none;">Prev</div>
    <div class="midbox">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navlink nextlink">Next</div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    <div class="navlink prevlink">Prev</div>
    <div class="midbox">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navlink nextlink" style="display:none;">Next</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What is the purpose of the `class='box'`?

Comment: class='box' : top 3 boxes like products with match that pagination is center, 
its not part of pagination.

Comment: Aahh, I see. I will try to apply your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not the case where I could apply your solution. However, I found out that if I delete `class="u-pagination-v1__item u-pagination-v1-4 g-rounded-50 g-pa-7-16"` of the button "Back", the pagination stays the same. In the case of the button "Next" it is different. Seems like the pagination goes to the right when this button disappears (because we reached the last page).

Comment: in your code add "absolute" position in Back and Next link and apply position set left and right 

and add position relative in parent element.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get it. I need to add absolute positions for buttons and then apply `float: right` or `float: left`, right?

Comment: no need to "float", add back link to "left:0; top:0;" and next link to "right:0; top:0;"

can u send me demo link which you are working i have given you solution with your classes and html.

Comment: `nav.text-center { text-align:center;}
  nav.text-center ul { text-align:center; display:block; overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; position:relative;}
  nav.text-center ul li { list-style:none; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}`

Comment: `nav.text-center ul li.float-sm-left { position:absolute; left:0; top:0;}
  nav.text-center ul li.float-sm-right { position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}`

Comment: I tried to do this and now it works perfectly fine! Thank you very much!